# Spring Boot - Junit unable to load configuration properties in junit test

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, properties

I have a `consumer.properties` file with the following contents in `src/main/resources`, and an accompanying Configuration class that loads and stores the file's contents into class member variables:

//`consumer.properties` file in `src/main/resources`:

```
com.training.consumer.hostname=myhost
com.training.consumer.username=myusername
com.training.consumer.password=mypassword
```

//ConsumerConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource(
        value= {"classpath:consumer.properties"}
        )
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="com.training.consumer")
public class ConsumerConfig {

    private String hostname;
    private String username;
    private String password;

    public ConsumerConfig() { }

    public String getHostname() {
        return hostname;
    }
    public void setHostname(String hostname) {
        this.hostname = hostname;
    }
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }
    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ConsumerConfig [hostname=" + hostname + ", username=" + username + ", password=" + password + "]";
    }
}
```

I also have a `ConfigsService` class that autowires the `ConsumerConfig` class to retrieve the individual properties:

```
@Component
public class ConfigsService {

    @Autowired
    ConsumerConfig consumerConfig;

    public ConsumerConfig getConsumerConfig() {
        return consumerConfig;
    }

    public void showConfig() {
        consumerConfig.toString();
    }

    public ConsumerConfig getConfig() {
        return consumerConfig;
    }
}
```

The properties are loaded up just fine when running the ConfigsService's methods.  The problem is in the unit tests, where invoking `configService.getConfig().getHostname()` returns a null value -- even after having created a `src/test/resources` directory, and adding my `consumer.properties` file in it:

```
@TestPropertySource("classpath:consumer.properties")
public class ConfigsServiceTest {

    @Mock
    ConsumerConfig consumerConfig;

    @InjectMocks
    ConfigsService configService;


    @Before
    public void beforeEach() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void someTest() {
        System.out.println(configService.getConfig().getHostname()); //outputs null here -- wth!
        Assert.assertTrue(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, are you running this with spring runner, otherwise you will not be spinning up a spring instance during the test?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you are getting null values because of the mock object. I will suggest using spring runner with context configuration which will load properties in the config class and create the bean.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {ConsumerConfig.class, ConfigsService.class})
@TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath:consumer.properties")
public class ConfigsServiceTest {

  @Autowired
  private ConfigsService configsService;

  @Test
  public void someTest() {
    Assert.assertNotNull(configService.getConfig().getHostname());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error may be because in the ConfigsServiceTest class you are establishing that your ConsumerConfig is a Mock and that is why it is not loading your configuration if you remove that code it should work